# I am using a waveshare 64x64 P3 RGB matrix LED display and i am planning to adjust the brightness of the display

Tags: adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

```
matrix = rgbmatrix.RGBMatrix(
    width = width_value, height=height_value, bit_depth=bit_depth_value,
    rgb_pins = [board.GP2, board.GP3, board.GP4, board.GP5, board.GP8, board.GP9],
    addr_pins = [board.GP10, board.GP16, board.GP18, board.GP20, board.GP22],
    clock_pin = board.GP11, latch_pin=board.GP12, output_enable_pin=board.GP13,
    tile = chain_height, serpentine=serpentine_value,
    doublebuffer = True)`
```

display = framebufferio.FramebufferDisplay(matrix, auto_refresh=True,rotation=180)
display.brightness=0.1

the display.brightness is not changing the display brightness.
If i give display.brightness=0 its not displaying anything
if i give display.brightness=0.1 it is showing the same amount of brightness when i give display.brightness=1. Ie other than 0 value the display brightness is not getting affected.

the display.brightness is not changing the display brightness.
If i give display.brightness=0 its not displaying anything
if i give display.brightness=0.1 it is showing the same amount of brightness when i give display.brightness=1. Ie other than 0 value the display brightness is not getting affected.